# SVN Restrict access using Wildcard?

Tags: svn, wildcard

Can we use wildcards in SVN to restrict path based access. I know this feature was not available three years back. Has this feature been added? Has anyone been able to implement it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this article on SVN site:
https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10#authzperf

Wildcards can be used from version 1.10 and later.